# MongoDB Compass stuck loading data

Tags: mongodb, compass

Compass was working fine until today.  Now I'm noticing the following behavior:

1. Very rarely, it gets stuck trying to connect.
2. When connecting is ok, then it gets stuck trying to load the data.  This happens 100% since today.
3. Using the mongo shell or a 3rd party client such as Studio 3T works fine.

Following are some info on my setup:

- Compass version: 1.10 and 1.12
- Mongo cluster is on Atlas
- My internet is fast

I'm actually taking a class at Mongo University and this problem has forced me to drop out :(  I still want to get to the bottom of it tho.